# Infinite amount of time when trying to synthesize behavioral VHDL code with divider

Tags: vhdl

I have a difficult question for "strong" solvers :

I am trying to synthesize the VHDL behavioral code which is shown at the end of this question.

When I used the line

m1Low := m1Low/m0Low;

the circuit was synthesizing and producing correct results. However, this was for a given input, fixed as constants in the code. When the input comes as signals from outside the circuit (here specifically the input hist which is an array of std_logic_vector), this does not synthesize anymore.  I have to replace the / with a divide function:

m1Low := to_integer(divide(to_unsigned(m1Low,32),to_unsigned(m0Low,32)));

the circuit synthesizes for a huge amount of time. I left it overnight and it does not complete synthesis.

What do you suggest that I do?

Thank you
Haris

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;


use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

library work;
use work.declarations.all;


entity behavioral_code is
generic ( NHIST : integer := 32 );
port (clk        : in  std_logic;   
      en         : in  std_logic;   
          hist       : in  vector_array;
          thres      : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0) );
end behavioral_code;

architecture Behavioral of behavioral_code is

begin

process(en,clk)

    type int_array is array (1 to NHIST) of integer;    
    variable m0Low : integer := 0;
    variable m1Low : integer := 0;
    variable m0High : integer := 0;
    variable m1High : integer := 0;
    variable varLow : integer := 0;
    variable varHigh : integer := 0;
    variable varWithin : integer := 0;
    variable varWMin : integer := 900000000;
    variable hist_var : int_array;
    variable invertFlag: integer := 0;             
    variable nHistM1: integer := 0;
    variable i: integer := 0;
    variable j: integer := 0;
    variable k: integer := 0;
    variable l: integer := 0;
    variable m: integer := 0;
    variable n: integer := 0;
    variable o: integer := 0;
    variable p: integer := 0;
    variable q: integer := 0;
    variable temp: integer :=0;
    variable thres_var: integer :=0;



    begin
    if(en = '1') then

            for k in 1 to NHIST loop   
                hist_var(k) :=to_integer(unsigned(hist(k-1)));
    end loop;


    --for k in 1 to NHIST loop          --COMMENT: OLD FIXED INPUT
    --  hist_var(k) :=k;
    --end loop;



    nHistM1 := NHIST-1;
    for i in 1 to  nHistM1 loop     
        m0Low   :=0;
        m1Low   :=0;
        m0High  :=0;
        m1High  :=0;
        varLow  :=0;
        varHigh :=0;        

        for j in 1 to i loop
            m0Low := m0Low + hist_var(j);
            m1Low := m1Low + (j-1) * hist_var(j);
        end loop;


        if m0Low = 0 then
        m1Low := i;
        else
                    --m1Low := m1Low/m0Low;
        m1Low := to_integer(divide(to_unsigned(m1Low,32),to_unsigned(m0Low,32)));
        end if;

        for m in i + 1 to  NHIST loop
            m0High := m0High + hist_var(m);
            m1High := m1High + (m-1) * hist_var(m);
        end loop;

        if m0High = 0 then
        m1High := i;
        else
                    --m1High := m1High /m0High;
        m1High :=to_integer(divide(to_unsigned(m1High,32),to_unsigned(m0High,32)));
        end if;


        for n in 1 to i loop
            varLow := varLow + (n - 1- m1Low) * (n -1- m1Low) * hist_var(n);
        end loop;



        for o in i+1 to NHIST loop
            varHigh := varHigh +(o -1- m1High) * (o -1- m1High) * hist_var(o);
        end loop;




            varWithin := m0Low * varLow + m0High * varHigh;

        if varWithin < varWMin then
            varWMin := varWithin;
            thres_var := i-1;
        end if;


    end loop;


    thres <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(thres_var, 32));

    end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

The declarations package is the following:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use ieee.std_logic_arith.ALL;
use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.ALL;


use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

package declarations is
--generic ( NHIST : integer := 6 );
  type vector_array is array (23 downto 0) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
  function  divide  (a : UNSIGNED; b : UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED;
end package declarations;

package body declarations is

function  divide  (a : UNSIGNED; b : UNSIGNED) return UNSIGNED is
variable a1 : unsigned(a'length-1 downto 0):=a;
variable b1 : unsigned(b'length-1 downto 0):=b;
variable p1 : unsigned(b'length downto 0):= (others => '0');
variable i : integer:=0;

begin
for i in 0 to b'length-1 loop
p1(b'length-1 downto 1) := p1(b'length-2 downto 0);
p1(0) := a1(a'length-1);
a1(a'length-1 downto 1) := a1(a'length-2 downto 0);
p1 := p1-b1;
if(p1(b'length-1) ='1') then
a1(0) :='0';
p1 := p1+b1;
else
a1(0) :='1';
end if;
end loop;
return a1;

end divide;

end package body;
```

The testbench is the following:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY testbench1 IS
END testbench1;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF testbench1 IS 

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

COMPONENT behavioral_code
 port ( clk        : in  std_logic; 
         en         : in  std_logic;    
       hist       : in  vector_array;
           --debug1      : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug10      : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug11     : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug2     : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug3     : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug4     : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug5     : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug6     : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug7     : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug8     : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
           --debug50    : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
          -- debug60    : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
       thres      : out std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0) );
 end component;




 --Inputs
  signal en : std_logic := '0';
  signal hist : vector_array := (others => '0');
  signal clk: std_logic := '0';
--Outputs
   signal thres : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  --signal debug1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  --signal debug10 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  --signal debug11 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  --signal debug2  :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
-- signal debug3  :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
 --signal   debug4  :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
 --signal   debug5  :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
 --signal   debug6  :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
 -- signal  debug7  :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
 --signal   debug8  :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
 --signal   debug50 :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);
 --signal   debug60 :  std_logic_vector ( 31 downto 0);


  -- No clks detected in port list. Replace <clk> below with 
  -- appropriate port name 

 constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

 BEGIN

-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 uut: behavioral_code PORT MAP (
      en => en,
      clk => clk,
     -- debug1 => debug1,
     -- debug10 => debug10,
     -- debug11 => debug11,
     -- debug2 => debug2,
      --debug3 => debug3,
      --debug4 => debug4,
      --debug5 => debug5,
      --debug6 => debug6,
      --debug7 => debug7,
      --debug8 => debug8,
      --debug50 => debug50,
      --debug60 => debug60,
      hist => hist,
      thres  => thres
    );

  clk_process :process
  begin
 clk <= '0';
 wait for clk_period/2;
 clk <= '1';
 wait for clk_period/2;
  end process;


  -- Stimulus process
  stim_proc: process
  begin     
  -- hold reset state for 100 ns.
  wait for 10 ns;
        en<='1';

  --wait for <clk>_period*10;

  -- insert stimulus here 

  wait;
 end process;

 END;
```

Comment: What chip? What compiler/synthesiser tools?

Comment: Virtex 5 the last in the list. Xilinxe ise version 11.1

Comment: Upgrading the tools may help somewhat as the synthesizer has got better.  But you are asking for a loooot of logic, so you may struggle.  If you have C already, take a look at the Xilinx C-to-gates tool.

Comment: This tool is free? It comes with Xilinx ISE?

Comment: I don't think its part of Webpack, no. FPGAs still require expensive software when creating high-end designs.

Answer (score 1):

be aware that synthesis generates hardware out of your code. the code looks as if just "software programmed" and not intended for synthesis ;-)
e.g. a VHDL "for loop" generates the code within the block several times. therefore your code results in a veeeery large design. think of re-writing the code in a more sequential way. Use a

`if rising_edge(clk) then`

in your process to use FF-stages.

BTW: if you tested it with constants, your synthesizer tool most probably did the division for you and just implemented the result; that's why it worked with constants!

Comment: What about using a divider by the code generator? I think that xilinx ise does not support if rising_edge(clk) inside for loops. The only tool that supports that is synplify.

Comment: the rising_edge statement is to be implemented at the at the very beginning of the process: process(clk)... begin... if rising_edge(clk)...; this way, the code within the process can be implemented with FFs. try to split your algorithm into several steps and several clock cycles. this is what I mean by a "more sequential way"... not all in parallel logic (for loop --> big design) but in sequential steps (smaller design)

Comment: if you use the xilinx ise divider from the ip-core generator, you see that it takes several clock cycles until a result is calculated. the number of cycles is related to your vector sizes and reported by the tool.

Comment: My code comes from a c code that does color binarization. The whole point is to try to do fast in VHDL something that is done slowly in c. If you observe, almost all the code is inside a big for loop. For that reason, it is not possible to break the code in peaces. Also, it is not possible to put if(rising_edge(clk)) at any point inside the code except for the beggining. The only way you can put clock is to put wait until (clk'event and clk='1') statements inside the for loops using synplify. But that synthesizes forever.

Comment: I am reallyyyy frustrated! I have been writing vhdl for 4 years but never have I seen something like that!

Comment: unfortunately it is really not possible to just take some c code, write it with vhdl syntax and expect it to run fast or efficient. however, don't get frustrated! with some practice you'll manage to split the algorithm into meaningful function blocks!

Comment: What you propose with a counter sounds like a good idea. But again I can synthesize the design in synplify with wait until (clk'event and clk='1') statements . There are no errors but the synthesis time is infinite even for small values of the circuit parameter (NHIST). Any ideas?

Comment: Hi again, I tried to implement what you propose with the counter but it is not synthesizable. I get the error "right range bound is not constant" . Are you sure that in a for loop the right range bound can be something different than a costant?

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion in Baldy's answer to supply the missing clock edge statement,  and supplying a guess at the contents of your missing package, I find that you omitted to supply the "divide" function.

So, restoring the intrinsic division, let's see what synthesis reports :

```
    =========================================================================
    Advanced HDL Synthesis Report

    Macro Statistics
    # Multipliers                                          : 2072
     31x2-bit multiplier                                   : 1
     31x3-bit multiplier                                   : 3
     31x4-bit multiplier                                   : 7
     31x5-bit multiplier                                   : 15
     32x32-bit multiplier                                  : 1986
     33x32-bit multiplier                                  : 60
    # Adders/Subtractors                                   : 4349
     32-bit adder                                          : 1373
     32-bit adder carry in                                 : 1984
     32-bit subtractor                                     : 992
    # Adder Trees                                          : 88
     32-bit / 10-inputs adder tree                         : 1
   ...
     32-bit / 7-inputs adder tree                          : 1
     32-bit / 8-inputs adder tree                          : 1
     32-bit / 9-inputs adder tree                          : 1
    # Registers                                            : 96
     Flip-Flops                                            : 96
    # Comparators                                          : 2077
     32-bit comparator greater                             : 31
     32-bit comparator lessequal                           : 62
   ...
     64-bit comparator lessequal                           : 62
    # Multiplexers                                         : 61721
     1-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                              : 61536
     32-bit 2-to-1 multiplexer                             : 185

    =========================================================================
```

And then it goes on to take a considerable time attempting optimisations. But really synthesis has gone far enough to tell you what you need to know : This is indeed a very big design; far larger than the task justifies.

I can only concur with his suggestion that you have to reorganise the computation across multiple clock cycles until its size is acceptable. Then, synthesis time will also be reduced to acceptable limits.

Also ... All that logic with only 96 flipflops? This is a very unbalanced design and likely to be as slow as molasses. Pipeline registers - lots of them - will be required to achieve acceptable performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas. I am going to come back with comments soon